# Oracle sql union with no duplicate on a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, is it possible to perform a `union` where the duplicate condition is on a single column rather than the entire row?

I have table `A`and `B` that have 2 columns: `item_name, price`. I'd like to create a view that for certain `item_names`, it looks in table `A` to see if the `item_name` is present, and if so use the `price` in `A`, if not go to `B` and use the `price` in `B`, then `union` the rest of `item_name` in `B` that have not yet been added to the view.

For example,

```
 Table A                Table B
 ----------------       ----------------
 item_name price        item_name price
 ----------------       ----------------
 shoe      10           shoe      8
 socks     2            socks     4
 shirt     5            t-shirt   3
 gloves    1            glasses   15
                        pants     7
```

For `shoe` and `socks` I'd like to use `table A`'s prices if available, and if not use `table B`. So in the end, my view should look like this:

```
 View
 -----------------------
 item_name price source
 -----------------------       
 shoe      10    A
 socks     2     A
 t-shirt   3     B
 glasses   15    B
 pants     7     B
```

I tried

```
 select * from A a
 where item_name in ('shoe', 'socks')
 union
 select * from B b
 where b.item_name not in 
     (select item_name from A
      where item_name in ('shoe', 'socks'))
```

Which I don't like because the query `select * from A where item_name in ('shoe', 'socks')` is duplicated. Is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for a join:

```
select coalesce(a.item_name, b.item_name) as item_name,
       coalesce(a.price, b.price) as price,
       (case when a.price is not null then 'A' else 'B' end) as source
from a full outer join
     b
     on a.item_name = b.item_name
```

Comment: +1, though I think OP wants only the Table B rows, so maybe it should be `right outer join` instead of `full outer join`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Oracle, I may suggest the following, it would do the trick

```
select NVL(A.ITEM_NAME,B.ITEM_NAME) AS ITEM_NAME, 
NVL(A.PRICE,B.PRICE) AS PRICE 
FROM A as a RIGHT JOIN B as b ON A.ITEM_NAME=B.ITEM_NAME
```

To understand why it works, simply try it without NVL, the resulting right join results

```
A_item  A_price     B_item  B_price
shoe    10          shoe    8
socks   2           socks   4
(null)  (null)      glasses 15
(null)  (null)      t-shirt 3
(null)  (null)      pants   7
```

Since you do not want the null values from table A, use [NVL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVL)

NVL has also equivalent functions in mysql/mssql etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    create view viewname as (
    select coalesce(a.item_name, b.item_name) as item_name,
       coalesce(a.price, b.price) as price,
       (case when a.item_name=b.item_name then 'A' else 'B' end) as source
from tablea a right outer join
     tableb b
     on a.item_name = b.item_name)
```

made slight change Gordon's ans